# crossdomain.xml issue causing "send failed" error

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-10, crossdomain.xml

In our environment we have both a primary and contingency server to ensure some continuity of operations in the event one site goes down. During testing of the contingency server we discovered a Flex based application will not allow users to login and returns a "Auth error: send failed". When monitoring network activity I see the following:

[image: Snip of Network Traffic showing Crossdomain aborted]

It looks to me like the cross domain policy is causing the issue as I do not see anything similar when I load the Flex application in our primary environment.

Here is the contents of the crossdomain.xml file found in our web root.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

What am I missing? Is the cross domain issue a red herring and there is something else going on that I am missing. Any suggestions on what to do?

EDIT: Not sure it matters but to be clear we are using HTTPS in both environments and when accessing the contingency server I use the fully qualified machine name as the DNS is set up to point to the primary server.

Comment: The request that was aborted is for localhost, not your server.  That means it is requesting the file locally (your computer). That seems odd doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, that seems very odd. I noticed that as well. Why would my computer request the file locally and not on the server? Also why does it do this in this environment and not the primary environment?

Comment: You may need to use cflogin and set the role or permission behind the scenes. We had a similar issue. The user's session wasn't being shared properly (I can't remember the exact details here but cflogin was definitely the fix for us).